# How to check SqlParameter is true with If

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I want to check sqlparameter is true on if statements like this;

```
        string sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail=@mail and passwd is null";
        string sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail=@mail and passwd=@password";
        SqlParameter prm1 = new SqlParameter("mail", txtMail.Text.Trim());
        SqlParameter prm2 = new SqlParameter("password", txtPassword.Text.Trim());
        if (sql1 == true)
        {
           
            MessageBox.Show("yes");
        }
        else if (sql2 == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("yes2");
        }
        {
            MessageBox.Show("no");
        }
```

Comment: Note: 1. You are missing **@** prefix in SQLParameter. 2. Your query was not executed, you need [`SqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) with provided `SqlConnection`, query, parameters. 3. You need [`.ExecuteScalar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to return first record of query result.

Comment: You trying to compare **Strings** `sql1`/`sql2` with **Boolean** `true`/`false`? Describe in details, which goal you trying to achieve, not *"i want smth"*.

Comment: 4. If your DB is MySQL, then you need `MySqlConnection`, [`MySqlCommand`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand.htm)

Comment: 5. The password is vunerable, without encrypt the password and check the DB. Please make sure your User records are inserted/updated with the encrypted password into DB.

Comment: Thank you for your comments but i just need how can i check sql1 or sql2 is true with any statements. This code is example dont focus the another faults.

Comment: What you mean under `sql1 or sql2 is true`? It can't be true or false because they are *query strings*.

Comment: I'm completely confused: are you trying to pass data in with these parameters or get data out? And what does "SqllParameter is true" mean given you are dealing with string parameters? And why would you check the `sql1` string, that's just a query string? And why have you tagged [tag:mysql] when you are clearly using SQL Server?

Comment: @Charlieface, I think he trying to check for records existance with provided `mail` and `password`. It can be achieved with `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` and then `reader.Read()` will return true or false.

Comment: if the mail is full and the password is empty in the database, I need to redirect to the registration form. how can I do that.

Comment: @Auditive yes you right

Comment: True in SQL is  1  and False in SQL is 0 and field must be in bit type.
if(fieldnameAsBit = 1) begin . . . .  end

Comment: @zambee can you give any simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather unclear what you are trying to do, but it *looks like* you might want code like this:

```cs
const string query = @"
SELECT CASE WHEN passwdHash is null THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
FROM users
WHERE mail = @mail and (passwdHash is null OR passwdHash = @passwdHash);
";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnString))
using (var comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    comm.Parameters.Add("@mail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtMail.Text.Trim();
    comm.Parameters.Add("@passwordHash", SqlDbType.Binary, 32) = SaltAndHashPassword(txtPassword.Text.Trim());
    conn.Open();
    var result = comm.ExecuteScalar() as int?;
    conn.Close();
    if (result == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("yes");
    }
    else if (result == 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("yes2");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("no");
    }
}
```

**Note the following**

- `using` blocks on all `Sql` objects
- Specify parameter types and lengths explicitly
- Hash the password and compare that instead
- Don't `select *`, just pass back a single column with a result
- Close the connection before blocking with a `MessageBox`

Comment: Thank you but i am completely confused. Could it be simpler?

Comment: Looks simple enough to me. What exactly are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I am getting an error "CS0019 '==' operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'"

Comment: It is done but now it is working just result==1. else if or else giving error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: Mmmm, just realized if you don't get a row then the result is `null` not `DBNull.Value`. Should be working now

Comment: I fix it. Thank you so much.